# The output still no logic in all of the integers values

Tags: c

well I'm doing this homework but I'm still not viewing the fault... When I run (after compiling without errors in gcc) seems to work fine... But when i put on the input, i.e. "254 34 199" the output returns: "There's two equal numbers. Try again"... Not logic at all.

What's the problem?

Thank you!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    puts("Enter three numbers separated by a space to determine what is the greatest, what is the one in the middle and what is the lowest.");

    int a, b, c;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

        int imax(int a, int b) {return a < b ? b : a;}
        int imin(int a, int b) {return a < b ? a : b;}

    int high = imax(imax(a, b), c);
    int low = imin(imin(a, b), c);

    int mid(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a<b && a>c) return a;
    else if (b<a && b>c) return c;
    else return b;
    }

    if (high == mid && mid == low) puts("All of the numbers are equal. Try again");

    else if (high == mid || high == low || mid == low) puts("There's two equal numbers. Try again"); /* This else if makes me crazy cause is not logic with a lot of combinations of three numbers! */

    else printf("The greatest are %d, the middle are %d and the lowest are %d\n", high, mid, low);
}
```

Comment: This compiles? You'd better turn on more warnings then... (`-Wall` on gcc). Defining functions within other functions should not be allowed.

Comment: @Thomas It's a much misused gcc extension.

Comment: @Thomas, even better would be to add `-std=c99` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the middle number in a wrong way, for example, if we put the values that you gave (254 34 199)in your calculation:

```
int mid = imax(imax(254, 34), imin(34, 199));
```

we get:

```
int mid = imax(254, 34);
```

which is:

```
int mid = 254;
```

instead of 199.

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix this? (Sorry, I'm new in C).

Comment: @user1178392 You're also new to "logic", "reason" and "math".

Comment: I don't want to ruin all the fun for you :) There are several approaches to do that.

Comment: Okay, I'll try, but can you tell me a hint to do this with math functions? Or it's better to do with logic functions? I'm just need the middle value right now.

Comment: I've updated the code up with something that I made... But I'm not sure if in that way can work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has already been pointed out by Binyamin. Here's a pointer to an alternative, probably better solution: [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). The case for three integers won't require any loops at all.

Comment: I don't see the point of implementing a bad algorithm like bubble sort.The C library has a qsort() function, if needed.

Comment: Bubble sort is not "bad" per se. On three integers, qsort will be no faster than bubble sort, and likely slower due to recursive function call overhead.

Comment: and on MP machines there is a parallel bubble sort that has quite good performance.

Comment: Assuming it is the qsort by [Bentley and McIlroy](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/profs/Luc.Maranget/421/09/bentley93engineering.pdf) It uses an insertion sort for arrays (and subarrays) with less than 7 values, so there is no recursion. But it is generalised, so it needs to handle the general case of n-byte element swaps. So qsort is likely slower for very small numbers of values. I haven't seen any article about a better implementation than B&M, and the last time I looked (years ago) IIRC my C library used theirs.